# Determine which statements are True, and which statements are False

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Determine which statements are True, and which statements are False

> 1. There are 3 consecutive False statements
> 2. This is The First True Statement
> 3. There are equal numbers of True and False statements
> 4. There are not equal numbers of True and False statements
> 5. There are 4 consecutive False statements
> 6. The First and Last statements are False
> 7. There are 3 consecutive statements which are False, False, True.
> 8. There are 3 consecutive True statements
> 9. There are 3 consecutive statements which are True, False, True.
> 10. There are 4 consecutive True statements

This puzzle have more than 1 solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Final answer

> There are five distinct possibilities: FTFTFFTTTT, TFFTFFTFFF, TFTFFFTTTF, FTTFFTTTFF, FTTFFTTFTF.

### Proof

First, assume statement 5 is true.

This implies statement 1 is also true. So the four consecutive false statements cannot be 1,2,3,4; they must be either 6,7,8,9 or 7,8,9,10. So 7,8,9 are all false, which means there can be no sequences of statements of the form FFT **or** TTT **or** TFT.

So the sequence of statements 3,4,5 (ending in a true statement) must be FTT. But now statement 2 is either true or false, so the sequence 2,3,4 must be either TFT or FFT. **Contradiction**.

> So **statement 5 is false.**

- Now assume statement 10 is true.

  Since statement 5 is false, the four consecutive true statements must be either 1,2,3,4 or 6,7,8,9 or 7,8,9,10. But if statement 2 is true, then statement 1 is false, so 1,2,3,4 cannot all be true. So 7,8,9 are all true. By our assumption, 10 is true and therefore 6 is false. We have FFTTTT for statements 5-10.

  Assume statement 1 is true, so that statement 2 is false. Note that exactly one of 3 and 4 is false, since they are opposites. So the three consecutive false statements must be 4,5,6, and the entire sequence is TFTFFFTTTT: six true statements and four false ones, making statement 3 false. **Contradiction.**

  So statement 1 is false, and there are no three consecutive false statements. Since 5 and 6 are false, this means 4 must be true, so 3 is false and 2 is true. Now the entire sequence is **FTFTFFTTTT**. There are no contradictions here, so this is a possible answer.

Let's see if there are any others: i.e. let's assume statement 10 is false.

- Assume statement 1 is true.

  This implies statements 2 and 6 are both false. Note also that exactly one of 3 and 4 is false.

  If 7 is false, then the sequence of false statements starting with 5,6,7 must continue until the end, so 8,9,10 are all false too, which means statement 5 is true, contradiction. So 7 is true, and we have TF??FFT??F.

  - If 9 is false, then 3 must be false (otherwise 1,2,3 would be TFT), so 4 is true, and 8 is false since there are no three consecutive true statements. This gives the entire sequence **TFFTFFTFFF**, which is another viable possibility.
  - If 9 is true, then the only way to get the three consecutive false statements required by 1 is if they are 4,5,6, so 4 is false and 3 is true. To make the counts of true and false statements agree, 8 must also be true, so we have **TFTFFFTTTF**, which is another viable possibility.
- Finally, assume statement 1 is false.

  Now 6 is true, so we have F???FT???F, and of course exactly one of 3 and 4 is true.

  - If 8 is true, then 6,7,8 must be the three consecutive true statements and 9 must be false (since we can't have four consecutive true statements). To avoid having a sequence TFT, 4 must be false, thus 3 is true, and then 2 must be true. So the entire sequence is **FTTFFTTTFF**, which is another viable possibility.
  - If 8 is false, then 9 must be true (otherwise 8,9,10 would be three consecutive false statements), so we have F???FT?FTF. If 7 were false, then the sequence 7,8,9 would be FFT; contradiction, so 7 is true. Now if 3 were false and 4 true, then the FFT sequence required by 7 must be 2,3,4, so 1,2,3 are three consecutive false statements, contradiction. So 3 is true and 4 false, and then 2 must be true to make the counts of true and false statements match. Thus the entire sequence is **FTTFFTTFTF**, another viable possibility.

Comment: The existence of 5 distinct answers shows that *whatever* clever things you will do, in the end, you will left with these 5 distinct cases. To handle this task alone (deal with the 5 cases) is complicated, so in essence, you are repeating the utterly boring, and automatic reasoning of a computer. You are not going to find any *nice* answers, because there are none: in part, because the question itself was poorly designed.

Comment: @Matsmath Finished! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This puzzle has surprisingly

> five solutions: {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}}.

There are no other solutions. Thanks @rand al'thor for pointing out a bug in how I selected 3-subsets.

---

> What happens is, that each of the 10 statements S1, S2, ..., S10, can be evaluated independently for any given 10-tuples. So, for example S1(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)=0, because in the 10-tuple {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1} there are NO three consecutive 0s. The task is then to solve the equation [S1(x),S2(x),...S10(x)]=x which you can do by exhaustively going through all 1024 10-tuples. In essence, you are looking for a fixpoint of the vector-valued function F(x):=[S1(x),S2(x),...,S10(x)].

Comment: FTFTFFTTTT also works.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out. I was unable to correctly specify what is a 3-consecutive subset (I missed out {5,6,7} and {6,7,8}, or alike).

Comment: Ok. I have not checked if this puzzle have multiple answer or not.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. False
> 2. True
> 3. False
> 4. True
> 5. False
> 6. True
> 7. True
> 8. False
> 9. True
> 10. False

Or:

> FTFTFFTFTF

Explanation:

> 7: There are 3 statements which are False, False, True.
> We could make it 5 as False, 6 as False and 7 as True. On 9, it's True False True. We could make 7 True (already), 8 false and 9 true. This fits in, completely. Now, let's start building up. At 2, it says that statement is true, so let's make that true. (don't remember the rest). I just realized this answer is wrong.

EDIT: I just realized this is wrong.

Comment: you have 3 as false

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Comment: Sorry, but **this doesn't work**: you claim statement 3 is false, but there *are* equal numbers of true and false statements in your list.